# How to vertically center text in div

Tags: html, css

I've tried about 6-7 different methods for centering this text vertically so it remains responsive and in the center of the div.

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p2NLK/

I've tried using positioning such as

```
margin-top: 40%;
```

or

```
margin-top: 20em;
```

to the h1 element to push the text down but its not fluid at all and breaks a lot.

Comment: Possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/q/20763508/703717

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css?rq=1#answer-8865463a) answer. It has some solutions.

Comment: Ok I've already tried all these techniques because my container is a position absolute this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
```

Works for horizontal center.

Try [this](http://jsbin.com/iquviq/30/edit) for vertically centered.

or

CSS

```
body, html, #wrapper {
width: 100%;
height: 100%
}

#wrapper {
display: table
}

#main {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align:center
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="main">
Content goes here
</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.
Do leave a feed back.

Comment: Sorry I should of been clearer it needs to be vertically centered

Comment: np. Edited my answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p2NLK/1/  See this fiddle for the solution implimented it still doesnt work :(

Comment: You haven't tried my latest solution..pl check

Comment: Yep i have :( hence why im posting check http://jsfiddle.net/k5yPM/ for proof

Comment: See, try this.
Include your container div in another div (say wrapper as in my eg) and assign that as a table(as exactly shown) and then do your stuff.

Comment: Dude, the third solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
replace margin-top: 40%; to following css

display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align:center;
```