# vertically align for floated element

Tags: css, css-float, vertical-alignment

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ovkgzmdv/)

I've the following markup:

```
<div id="all">
<div id="one">one</div>
<div id="two">two</div>
<div id="main">main para goes here</div>
</div>
```

and the following css:

```
#all{
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
}
#one{
    float: left;
}
#two{
    float: right;
}
#main{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 250px;
}
```

I wanted to align vertically but no success even after using pseudo technique. Vertical alignment should work at least ie8.

**Please note: I can't change the markup. It means I can't avoid using float.**

So, is there any way to make it success?

Comment: What pseudo technique? And what is the problem? Everything is vertically aligned ins't it?

Comment: Is it allowed to specify `width` on `#one`/`#two` elements?

Comment: check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/ovkgzmdv/1/ which works but two is not floated to the right

Comment: @HashemQolami yes, I can use width but not height...

Comment: Oldschool trick: First set all margins and paddings 0. Then #all with position:absolute to top:50% and with margin-top:-150px as the height of #all is known. http://jsfiddle.net/d0zcegsc/1/

Comment: @AxelRichter I wanted to align it's content not container...

Comment: @C-linkNepal I could get it to work on IE9+ but to support IE8, is it allowed to use a percentage unit for the width of `#main`? instead of `250px`? to get rid of using `calc()` expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, using CSS floats gives no chance to align the floated element vertically in their container *(regardless of using CSS flexible box method)*.

Hence I'd go with `inline-block`s so that I can align them by `vertical-align: middle` declaration.

So far so good, but the `#two` element must be positioned at the right side of the container without using CSS floats. Hence we have to specify `width` of the columns [to reorder the columns via `relative` positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339764/changing-html-column-order-on-specific-width/25340070#25340070):

To get this approach to work on **IE8**, we have to use percentage units for the width columns. Saying that we'll end up with:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/ovkgzmdv/8/)**

```css
#all {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;

    font-size: 0; /* To remove the white-space between inline-block columns */
}

#all:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}


#one, #two, #main {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;

    font-size: 16px; /* Reset the font-size to the default value */
}

#one, #two { width: 30%; }
#two { left: 40%; text-align: right; } /* Push the column to the right by 40% */
#main{ right: 30%; width: 40%; }       /* Pull the column to the left  by 30% */
```

This will work on **IE8+** *(not remember the requirements of IE6/7)*. However for **IE9+** we can use `calc()` expression to specify the width of columns like so:

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/ovkgzmdv/6/)**

```css
#one, #two {
    width: calc((100% - 250px) / 2);
}

#two{
    left: 250px;
    text-align: right;
}
#main{
    right: calc((100% - 250px) / 2);

    width: 250px;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/ovkgzmdv/2/)**

Using flex-box

css

```
#all{
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center
}
#one{
    float: left;
    order: 1;
}
#two{
    float: right;
    order: 3;
}
#main{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 250px;
    order: 2;
}
```

Comment: But OP want to support IE8 also :)

Comment: While true, it doesn't fit the OP's need: `Vertical alignment should work at least ie8.`

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox FlexBox doesn't work on older browser versions.

Comment: +1 - To the best of my knowledge, this is currently the only way in CSS to vertically center a floated element. [Here are some other vertical centering methods](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20764040/703717), but only flexbox will center floats

Answer (score 0):

Using a bit of jquery and css you can easily center the elements that you want:

**CSS**

```
div{
    outline:solid gray 1px;
}
#all{
    height: 300px;
}
#one{
    float: left;
    position:relative;
}
#two{
    float: right;
    position:relative;
}
#main{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 250px;
    position:relative;
}
```

**JS**

```
function center(element){
            var all = $("#all");
            if(element.height()<all.height()){
                  element.css(
                      "top",
                      ((all.height()/2)-(element.height()/2))+"px"
                  );  
            }
}

center($("#one"));
center($("#two"));
center($("#main"));
```

**FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/ovkgzmdv/5/

Comment: Maybe in pure css I don't know, but this solution is such simple, why not use it ?