# Text inside a div to align both vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` and a `<p>` inside the div containing some text.

Horizontal alignment is achievable using `text-align:center` property but I am not able to middle it vertically.

I ve checked other related solutions, but they are specific to that particular problem and not suited for any div size.

I need a solution that could possibly be suited for any div of varying dimensions (in my case it is 100% both width and height).

Here is my **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o3smkvk9/)**

Comment: here are some ways: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20764040/703717

Comment: You can use table - cell see this [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/o3smkvk9/5/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `top: calc(50% - 1em)` on `p` to center it vertically.

```
p {
    position: relative;
    top: calc(50% - 1em);
}
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/o3smkvk9/4/)

---

### Solution for Multiline text:

The idea is to get the `height` of the text, divide it by `2` and use it in `calc(50% - ****)` when the page loads or the window is resized. Then find the rule for the `p` tag and modify the `top` property.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/o3smkvk9/11/)

```js
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];

function doMath() {
  var ss = document.styleSheets;
  for (k = 0; k < ss.length; k++) {
    var rules = ss[k];
    for (l = 0; l < rules.cssRules.length; l++) {
      var r = rules.cssRules[l];
      if (r.selectorText == "p") {
        r.style.top = 'calc(50% - ' + String(parseInt(getComputedStyle(p).height.slice(0, -2)) / 2) + 'px)'
      }
    }
  }
}

doMath();
window.onresize = doMath;
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#dvTxt {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
p {
  position: relative;
  top: calc(50% - 7.5px);
}
```

```html
<div id="dvTxt">
  <p>This is my text. I want it to be centered vertically This is my text. I want it to be centered vertically This is my text. I want it to be centered vertically This is my text. I want it to be centered vertically This is my text. I want it to be centered
    vertically This is my text. I want it to be centered vertically This is my text. I want it to be centered vertically This is my text. I want it to be centered vertically This is my text. I want it to be centered vertically This is my text. I want
    it to be centered vertically This is my text. I want it to be centered vertically This is my text. I want it to be centered vertically This is my text. I want it to be centered vertically This is my text. I want it to be centered vertically This is
    my text. I want it to be centered vertically This is my text. I want it to be centered vertically This is my text. I want it to be centered vertically</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I like this answer, but remember, if you're going to use `calc` be sure it's compatible with your users' browsers first.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: @bvpx - It does not need any prefixes. [Check out the browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

Comment: What happens if your text length is huge. You started at middle and it goes down and the space above the middle is always empty. http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/o3smkvk9/2/

Comment: @SridharDD - Well, I'll add JavaScript solution for that.

Comment: This is working nicely. But Could you provide a solution where the text is direcly in the <div> tag and not inside the <p> tag?

Comment: @dasher121 [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/o3smkvk9/6/) (no script required)

Comment: @chipCHocolate.py :: Gud work. How about my try http://jsfiddle.net/DDSridhar/3u1w7taj/ . Is there any issue arise in this method?

Comment: @SridharDD - Your solution works too. I was focusing on `calc()` solution so without JavaScript it wasn't possible.

Answer (score 2):

The following CSS will works.

[Text aligned center Vertically](http://jsfiddle.net/DDSridhar/3u1w7taj/)

CSS:

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;   
}

#dvTxt{
    background-color:lightblue;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table;
}

#span {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: normal;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="dvTxt">
    <p id="span">This is my text. I want it to be centered vertically</span>
</div>
```

Comment: your fiddle redirects to the question link

Answer (score 1):

add padding-top:50% to #dvTxt . It is not perfect solution for varying content but you will get idea what to do next. For the now padding-top:50% is perfect for your fiddle example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
position: absolute
```

see [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kapantzak/o3smkvk9/3/)

CSS:

```
html,body{
height:100%;
width:100%;  
}

#dvTxt{
background-color:lightblue;
height:100%;
width:100%;
position: relative;
}

p {
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one line per element then easier solution would be using line-height.

```
#dvTxt{
    background-color:lightblue;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height:8em;
}

http://jsfiddle.net/o3smkvk9/10/
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use padding attribute to center your text vertically as

```
#dvTxt{
background-color:lightblue;
height:100%;
width:100%;
text-align: center;
padding:50% 0;
```

}